# Is it decidable whether one language is polytime reducible to another?

Tags: complexity-theory

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two decision problems.

Is there an algorithm deciding whether $L_1 \leq_P L_2$, that is, whether $L_1$ is reducible to $L_2$ in polynomial time?

Comment: How are $L_1$ and $L_2$ given to the algorithm?

Comment: Elaborate the possible permutations of, decidable, undecidable languages anf  Polynomial time and Non-deterministic polynomial time algirithms.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. At any rate, once you pose your question in a well-defined way, the answer will likely be that the problem is undecidable.

Comment: I guess then i didn't get your question, if you can eleborate more , i can add it.

Comment: The input to an algorithm has to be finite. Decision problems are infinite objects. You can't given a decision problem as an input. Therefore I find it hard to understand your question.

Comment: I want to ask that whether there exists an algorithm  to which if i give input as my two existing algorithms L1 and L2 then  I ask whether L1 reducible to L2 OR L2 reducible to L1 then it will give me answer as "Yes" Or "NO"  in finite time. ( Now i dont know what i asked is valid or not, if yes then please answer and if no then what is the flaw in my concepts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your question is whether the language $$L = \{\langle M_1\rangle; \langle M_2\rangle\mid L(M_1)\leq_\mathrm{p} L(M_2)\}$$ is decidable, where $\langle M\rangle$ is the description of Turing machine $M$ and $\leq_\mathrm{p}$ denotes polynomial-time many-one reducibility.

**This language is undecidable.**

The only language that is many-one reducible to $\Sigma^*$ is $\Sigma^*$ itself.  This is because a many-one reduction from $X$ to $\Sigma^*$ must, by definition, map all "no" instances of $X$ to "no" instances of $\Sigma^*$. However, $\Sigma^*$  has no "no" instances, so the reduction can only exist if $X$ also has no "no" instances, i.e., if $X=\Sigma^*$.

So, now let $Y$ be any Turing machine that accepts every input.  The language $H=\{\langle M\rangle\mid \langle M\rangle;\langle Y\rangle\in L\}$ is clearly reducible to $L$. But $H$ is the language of Turing machines that accept every input, which is undecidable.

Comment: A good explanation. May be I couldn't able to ask properly but expecting this kind of explanation. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_2$ be some easy to decide language. For example,

$$L_2 = \{ \omega : |\omega| \equiv 0 \mod 2 \}$$

Then reducing instances of $L_1$ to instances of $L_2$ is as hard as deciding $L_1$ itself, and your question boils down to:

> Given a description of a TM halting on every input, can you simulate it in polynomial time?

This is undecidable, which you can prove by the same argument as for the Halting problem.